# Not able to move label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This is for a simple programming project I'm doing in python where I wanted to create a Windows 98-style password input thing. However, label2 refuses to move.

```
from tkinter import *

ws = Tk()
ws.title('Authentication')
ws.geometry('430x240')
ws.config(bg='white')

img = PhotoImage(file="Error Message.png")
label = Label(
    ws,
    image=img
)
label.place(x=0, y=0)




label2 = Label(ws, text= 'Please enter your password:',font=('W95FA', 20))
label2.place(x=117, y=120)
label2.pack()
    

text = Text(
    ws,
    height=1,
    width=32,
    font =('W95FA', 10)
)
text.place(x=116, y=125)

button = Button(
    ws,
    text='         Submit         ',
    bg='blue',
    fg='white',
    relief=RAISED,
    font=('W95FA', 18)
)
button.place(x=155, y=161)

ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: A `Text` widget with `height=1` is ideally a `Entry` widget. To answer your question, remove `label2.pack()`.

Comment: Calling `.place()` on the widget is pointless if you're immediately going to call `.pack()` on it.